# $\left\{\frac{1}{n}\right\}$ converges to $\frac{1}{2}$ in some metric space $(\mathrm{X}, \mathrm{d})$

Tags: convergence-divergence, compactness, cauchy-sequences

Consider the space $X=[0,1]$ Then

A) $\left\{\frac{1}{n}\right\}$ converges to $\frac{1}{2}$ in some metric space $(\mathrm{X}, \mathrm{d})$

B) $\left\{\frac{1}{n}\right\}$ converges to 1 in some metric space $(X, d)$

C) $\left\{\frac{1}{n}\right\}$ is not Cauchy in some metric space $(\mathrm{X}, \mathrm{d})$

D) All of these

For the first one
For any one-to-one function $f d(x, y)=|f(x)-f(y)|$ defines a metric.  I can choose a function $f$ such that $f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) \rightarrow f\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$. Hence first option correct.

What about the other options ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: what is the question ?

Comment: What id the distance for distinct $n,m$ in the discrete metric space?

Comment: $f(x)=1-x$ would suffice for B, if your statement about one-to-one functions is correct

Comment: Perhaps $f(x)=1/x$ would suffice for C

Comment: For C) choose discrete metric. In a discrete space space a sequence is Cauchy sequence iff  it is eventually constant. (Why?)